# PHP - HTML - Javascript - Submit text from textarea by pressing enter button

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I'm making a simple chat using html-php-javascript.
I wanna submit text from textarea to log file because "chatbox" will load the chats from there.

I wrote the code to submit text in textarea at "admin_post.php" and it works.

However, admin only can do that by pressing "send" button.
Is it possible to make javascript so when admin pressing "enter" on the keyboard, it will do as same as pressing "send" button in form?

Here's the html code in admin_post.php:

```
<form id="admintextform" name="message" action="">
            <?php $adminmsg = !empty($_POST['adminmsg']) ? $_SESSION['adminmsg'] : '';?>
            <textarea class="admintextarea" name="adminmsg" id="adminmsg" size="63" /><?php echo $adminmsg; ?></textarea>
            <input name="adminsubmitmsg" type="submit"  id="adminsubmitmsg" value="Send" />
        </form>
```

and for the "send" button script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //If user submits the form
        $("#adminsubmitmsg").click(function(){  
        var adminmsg = $("#adminmsg").val();
            $.post("admin_post.php", {text: adminmsg});             
            $("#adminmsg").attr("value", "");
            return false;
        });
</script>
```

I've tried this below script to solve my problem but it doesn't work. I hope the javascript below could do exactly same as the "send" button script above just by pressing enter button on the keyboard.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#admintextarea").keypress(function (e) {
            if(e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
                var adminmsg = $("#adminmsg").val();
                $.post("admin_post.php", {text: adminmsg});             
                $("#adminmsg").attr("value", "");
                return false;
            }
        });
</script>
```

Please help me and thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Can you specify what is going wrong? what is your expected behavior and what you actually get?

Comment: Hi. I can't submit the text in textarea into the log chat file by press enter button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.  If you format your code to eliminate scrolling, you make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: thank you. I've removed some unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there was a problem with your HTML. you have closed the `textarea` tag on opening.

For the solution, I hope you find this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lozzq3x9/1/) helpful. Here's the code:

```
$("#adminmsg").on('keypress', function(e){
  if (e.which == 13)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).val());
    $(this).val("");
  }
});
```

Key points:

1. You've got the selector wrong. the `#` corresponds to IDs, `.` corresponds to classes.
2. Your code may be run before the document is fully loaded; hence it can't find an element to bind. Use `on` instead to do a binding to the corresponding selector anytime on the page; or use put your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code */ });` to be executed after the page is fully loaded and ready.

Comment: oh my. thank you so much. Your first point is right, I've made a mistake between class and name/id of my textarea.